# Highcharts, show hovered point label only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to show the xAxis label (not data labels!) on point hover only.
Example: in the beginning, all the labels are on enabled: false, and I want to enable it on specific point only.

if it's not possible, even show it on hover only is also good, cause this doesn't work for me either:

```
 series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        enableMouseTracking : true,
        data: chartData,
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function(e){
                    console.log("Mouse Over", this.series.xAxis.userOptions.labels);
                    this.series.xAxis.userOptions.labels.enabled = true;
                },
                mouseOut: function(e) {
                    console.log("Mouse Out", this.series.xAxis.userOptions.labels);
                    this.series.xAxis.userOptions.labels.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

and please, no jquery!

Comment: Why you don't want to use jQuery? Please look at this example, made with xAxis.update() method: http://jsfiddle.net/ru2fgwso/2/

Comment: jQuery adds a lot of unnecessary lines of code. i'm asking the question as part of an enterprise company, which means that my code should be as light as it can, which again means, no jQuery! :)

Comment: So maybe this example will help you with your problem? :) http://jsfiddle.net/ru2fgwso/4/

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4e91fso6/) should work for you I suppose

Comment: Grzegorz,  The children array contains no childs, working to see why, and Rahul, didnt really understood what did you send? cause it looks static, nothing changed on hover

Comment: @AvihayMenahem sorry, did I misunderstand the question? do you want to show dataLabels for a few points or do you want to show datalabels for a few points but only on hover?